# Random Item Generator Unexpected EOF while parsing Error Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, syntax

Hello I am trying to make a Generator for asteroid types, and names. The finished product should make items like this:

```
MUS-786 A Type
AKL-675 C Type
BHF-877 B Type
```

Etc.

I already have the code for making the String of numbers, and Letters with the hyphen in between:

```
import string, random
def pick(num):
    for j in range(num):
        print("".join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(3)])+"-"+"".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(3)])
```

It works great, but i am trying to put a random asteroid type in as well (A Type, B Type, C type)

Here is the final code i was using:

```
import string, random
def pick(num):
    for j in range(num):
        print("".join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(3)])+"-"+"".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(3)])+" "+"".join([random.randint('A Type','B Type','C Type')])
```

This Gave me an error saying that there was an unexpected EOF when parsing.

What does `EOF` mean? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for editing Bhargav.

Comment: it means end of file ... probably mismatched brackets or quotes

Comment: Hmm... Any ideas for fixing this issue?

Comment: `random.randint('A Type','B Type','C Type')` isn't valid, either.

Comment: You are missing a `)` at the end of the `print` statement.

Comment: I fixed the error but when I ran the program i got this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    pick(1)
  File "/Users/James/Desktop/Asteroid Name Generator.py", line 4, in pick
    print("".join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(3)])+"-"+"".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(3)])+" "+"".join([random.randint('A Type','B Type','C Type')]))
TypeError: randint() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: I think you want `random.choice(['A Type','B Type','C Type'])`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis on the last line

```
print("".join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(3)])+"-"+"".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(3)])+" "+"".join([random.randint('A Type','B Type','C Type')]))
```

Is the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

```
import string, random
def pick(num):
    for j in range(num):
        print("".join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(3)])+"-"+"".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(3)])+" "+"".join(random.sample(['A Type','B Type','C Type'], 1)))
```

This will work. I replaced `random.randint` with `random.sample` and removed the `[]` around `random.randint` since `random.sample` returns a list.

You can use this as the last line as well, using `random.choice()`:

```
print("".join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(3)])+"-"+"".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(3)])+" "+ random.choice(['A Type','B Type','C Type']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.choice` to get a random value from a list, then add it to your code:

```
import string, random
def pick(num):
    for j in range(num):
        print("".join([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(3)])+"-"+"".join([random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(3)]+" "+random.choice(["A", "B", "C"])+" Type")
```

As such:

```
>>> pick(5)
MYO-078 B Type
TYR-215 C Type
IDY-604 C Type
FRA-272 A Type
WLJ-576 A Type
>>> pick(0)
>>> pick(3)
NEJ-767 A Type
PVD-879 C Type
ACP-344 A Type
```